# JQuery DataTables - AJAX loading message modal dialog

Tags: jquery, datatables, modal-dialog, loading, message

Hi I am using the JQuery DataTables plugin, i have it running perfectly but i need to show a modal dialog with a loading gif during the loading of the table. I mean if there a way that in top of the table that says 'Processing...' i can show the modal dialog.

Actually i try:

```
$("#loading").dialog("open");
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/Lq/Distribution?total=100",
    "success": fnsuccessComplete
} );
```

And in the fnsuccessComplete function i add the

```
$("#loading").dialog("close");
```

But if i fill the datatable it not show the dialog, if i comment the code to fill the DataTables it shows the dialog

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no `success` option in jQuery.dataTable.
I think you want to use `fnInitComplete`.

Check the documentation : http://datatables.net/ref

Comment: Thanks Magus for your reply, maybe is not in the documentation but for sure it works, anyway that is not the problem, the main problem is that i can't show the loading modal :(